# Strange PDF scanned character rendering in Android

Tags: pdf

I am using Android 4.0 (ICS) on a Samsung Nexus S 4G.  I have a PDF of a scanned book (text/graphics).  The PDF displays fine on a PC.  On the Android device, every single "d" and "o" character has the white space in the center (i.e. the "hole") filled in completely with black.  I've tried a half dozen different viewers and they all display it the same way.  I've tried re-rendering/printing the PDF on the computer before putting it on the mobile device, and still no luck.

I'm guessing it has to do with some Android system level driver that is shared between all the viewers I download.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What software are you using on PC to read it?

Comment: @DanHulme On PC it works fine with Adobe Reader.  On Android, the mobile Adobe Reader is one of the many apps I've tried.